# Implement Event listener and dispatcher

Tags: go, event-listener, dispatcher

I have created a CLI in Go. CLI is having variety of command like `create/delete/update rules` and also supports more related variety of commands.

Now, my use case is:

Whenever user fires any command in CLI eg: `get rule`, I want to configure and event listener. The goal of the event listener is to basically register/write in a file all the actions/tasks happened behind the scenes to complete that `get rule` request.

Actions/Tasks which can be associated with a `get rule` request is:

- Validate query params.
- Generate user token.
- Send the HTTP request with the token an params.
- Get the success/fail response.

I want to record all these actions associated with any event like `get rule` and write it in a file.

I tried to refer this: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/2qdl/event-listener-and-dispatcher-example-with-golang

But I'm not sure how to link it with my CLI. Is it even a correct way to set up Event listeners in the code. Or I have do something altogether different to achieve the use case listed above.

I would appreciate any help/guidance. Please point me to some examples.

Comment: It will be simpler to call a function to log the events.

Comment: i downvote because this post lacks your attempt at solving the probelm and is too general. A simple event listener implementation consist of a callback. A more complex implementation has pre/post handlers, filters and whoknowswhat added complexity that might be totally irrelevant to the task.